# Example of dispatch after in Swift

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

Xcode has a **GCD: Dispatch After** code snippet for Objective-C:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(<#delayInSeconds#> * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    <#code to be executed after a specified delay#>
});
```

What is the equivalent code snippet for Swift?

Answer (score 10):

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (Int64)(<#delayInSeconds#> * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    <#code to be executed after a specified delay#>
}
```

The equivalent of `int64_t` is `Int64`, also the block could be called via curly braces at the end of the function call.